# Swift AppIntent when include Parameter always ask for confirmation

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am trying to add voice control (by Siri) to a MacOS project. So I can just speak to sth like "overlay to the left 10"

Expected from the framework:

- Siri recognizes the shortcut by saying "Overlay to the left 10"
- the parameters "to the left" and "10" are recognised.

Actually how it works:

- Siri only recognizes saying literally "Overlay Direction" and then Siri asks for "What direction", and then "How many pixels"

My question is can AppIntent recognize the parameter directly from the command? Without confirmation on every parameter? Many thanks!

```
enum Direction:String{
    case left, right, up, down
}

extension Direction: AppEnum{
    static var caseDisplayRepresentations: [Direction : DisplayRepresentation] = [
        .down: "down",
        .up: "up",
        .left: "to the left",
        .right: "to the right",
    ]
    
    static var typeDisplayName: LocalizedStringResource = "Direction"
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Direction"
}

struct MoveGridIntent: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Overlay Direction"
    static var description = IntentDescription("move the grid")
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true

    @Parameter(title: "Direction", description: "the direction the overlay is going to move", requestValueDialog: IntentDialog("Which direction"))
    var direction: Direction
    
    @Parameter(title: "pixels", inclusiveRange: (1, 50))
    var pixels: Int
       
    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Overlay \(\.$direction) \(\.$pixels)")
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        print("MoveGridIntent", "move overlay", direction, "for \(pixels) pixels !!")
        return .result()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add App Intents to your Shortcuts app on installation, by implementing an `AppShortcutsProvider`, like so:

```swift
struct MyShortcuts : AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        AppShortcut(
            intent: MoveGridIntent(),
            phrases: ["Move overlay by \(\.$pixels) \(\.$direction) with \(.applicationName)"])
    }
}
```

It is important, that you use `applicationName` within each of your provided phrases, otherwise they won't be recognized.

I'm currently figuring this out for a project of my own and noticed, that it gets icky the more parameters and specialized vocabulary are involved. It should work fine for your example though.

**EDIT: You can only have one dynamic parameter in your invocation phrase! The above example won't work.**

In case it doesn't - I'm guessing here, still working on it myself - you might need to add `resolvers` on your parameters and/or a `AppIntentVocabulary.plist` to your localization (not sure yet, whether this only has an effect on old style SiriKit implementations).

I also recommend watching https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10170/ and https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10032

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Adding AppShortcutsProvider still would not get recognized in the activation phase. In fact only the phase showed in shortcut can be recognized. No one word more or less. 

 In the video you post "Implement App Shortcuts with App Intents" they talked about parameterized activation phase, the implementation is more difficult and I am not sure Int can also be parameterized in the activation phase like I want.

Comment: I tried the old Sirkit BTW, I don't think SiriKit supports parameters in the activation phase. In XCode they promote that you convert it to AppIntents.

I see your Edit only allow one dynamic parameter (Actually I just need static parameters), I will try again next week. Thanks!